# How to properly evaluate postfix notations in java?

Tags: java, expression, postfix-mta, notation

I've already made my code and it's working for some cases and isn't for other cases. It's hard to solve the level of precedence because of its complexity especially when it comes to relational and logical operators. I can already successfully convert infix to postfix notation but can't successfully evaluate the postfix.

```
     import java.util.*;
        import java.lang.Character;
        public class PostEvaluator
        {
            private Stack stack;
            private Queue queue;
        
            public PostEvaluator()
            {
                stack = new Stack(256);
                queue = new Queue();
            }
        
        
            //this function will check if the character being checked is an operator or not
            private static boolean isOperator(String c)
            {
                if (!Character.isLetterOrDigit(c.charAt(0)))
                    return true;
                else
                    return false;
            }
        
            //this function will calculate the necessary calculation needed
            private int operate (int x, int y, String operator)
            {
                int result = 0;
                switch (operator)
                {
                    case "*":
                        result = x * y;
                        break;
                    case "/":
                        if (y != 0)
                            result = x / y;
                        else
                        {
                            System.out.println("Division by zero error!");
                            System.exit(0);
                        }
                        break;
                    case "+":
                        result = x + y;
                        break;
                    case "-":
                        result = x - y;
                        break;
                    case "%":
                        result = x % y;
                        break;
                    case "^":
                        result = x ^ y;
                        break;
                    case ">":
                        if (x > y)
                            return 1;
                        else
                            return 0;
                    case "<":
                        if (x < y)
                            return 1;
                        else
                            return 0;
                    case ">=":
                        if (x >= y)
                            return 1;
                        else
                            return 0;
                    case "<=":
                        if (x <= y)
                            return 1;
                        else
                            return 0;
                    case "!=":
                        if (x != y)
                            return 1;
                        else
                            return 0;
                    case "==":
                        if (x == y)
                            return 1;
                        else
                            return 0;
                    case "&&":
                        result = x & y;
                        break;
                    case "||":
                        result = x | y;
                        break;
                }
                return result;
            }
        
            private int notOperate (int x)
            {
                if (x == 0)
                    return 1;
                else
                    return 0;
            }
        
            //this function will evaluate the post fix
            public String evaluatePostFix(String input)
            {
                String val1, val2, result = "", temp;
                int  intVal1, intVal2;
                Scanner kb = new Scanner(input);
                //splits the input by operand
                kb.useDelimiter(" ");
        
                do
                {
                    queue.enqueue(kb.next());
                } while (kb.hasNext());
        
                do
                {
                    //assign the temp of the first data in the queue
                    temp = (String) queue.dequeue();
        
                    if (!(temp.equals("")))
                    {
                        //if the value is not an operator, push it to the stack
                        if (!isOperator(temp)) {
                            stack.push(temp);
        
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            if (!stack.isEmpty())
                            {
                                if (!(temp.equals("!")))
                                {
                                        //assign the val 1 the last item in the stack to be evaluated
                                        val1 = (String) stack.pop();
                                    if (!stack.isEmpty()) {
                                        val2 = (String) stack.pop();
                                        intVal1 = Integer.parseInt(val1);
                                        intVal2 = Integer.parseInt(val2);
                                        result = Integer.toString(operate(intVal2, intVal1, temp));
                                        stack.push(result);
                                    }
                                    else
                                    {
                                        System.out.println("Missing Operand/s Error");
                                        System.exit(0);
                                    }
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    val1 = (String) stack.pop();
                                    intVal1 = Integer.parseInt(val1);
                                    result = Integer.toString(notOperate (intVal1));
                                    stack.push(result);
                                }
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                System.out.println("Missing Operand/s Error");
                                System.exit(0);
                            }
                        }
                        if (result.equals(""))
                            result = temp;
                    }
                }while (!queue.isEmpty());
        
                return result;
            }
        }
```

I've only seen postfix evaluation for arithmetic expressions without relational and logical operators

Comment: Have you tried narrowing the problem down?

Comment: what do you mean by narrowing down the problem

Comment: The problem is probably not everywhere in your 170 lines, but in some section of it, right? Have you tried finding what that section is? One way to do this is to pick a simple example that doesn't work, say `1 2 +`, and go through it by hand. On paper you would find that it should queue 1, then 2, then +. So you add a `System.out.println("Queued: " + temp);`, run the program, and make sure it prints "Queued: 1", "2", "+". If it does, great, that part works. If it doesn't, then that's where the bug is. Then you can continue. This only requires logic and deduction, not intuition or experience.

Comment: 1. "It's working for some cases and isn't for other cases": other cases such as what? What expected output? What actual output? 2. "It's hard to solve the level of precedence": No it isn't. There is no operator precedence in postfix, or rather the notation already expresses it: you don't have to do anything about it yourself. Unclear what you're asking; needs details or clarity; and needs debugging details.

Comment: As a matter of fact your code is working perfectly, given working implementations of `Stack` and `Queue`. So either there is something wrong with one or both of those, or your expectations of your test cases are incorrect.